# How to save and read image into memory/sdcard cache via Picasso?

Tags: android, picasso

I use Picasso in my Android app.

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(mContentImages.get(position).url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_photo)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_no_image)
                .into(imageView);
```

And **when context change - it will download again.**

So i want to know, how to setup Picasso to save images into sdcard and read from it, notwithstanding context changes?

Comment: didn't picasso managed it by itself?

Comment: @SarthakMittal every time when i relaunch application images download again.

Comment: If i remember correctly, picasso does not offers much options, i think you would be better off using UIL or Fresco?

Answer (score 1):

For caching, I would use OkHttp interceptors to gain control over caching policy. Check out this sample that's included in the OkHttp library. Check this link, [square/okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/recipes/RewriteResponseCacheControl.java)

Here's how I'd use it with Picasso -

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.networkInterceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            return originalResponse.newBuilder().header("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)).build();
        }
    });

    okHttpClient.setCache(new Cache(mainActivity.getCacheDir(), Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    OkHttpDownloader okHttpDownloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(mainActivity).downloader(okHttpDownloader).build();
    picasso.load(imageURL).into(viewHolder.image);
```

Comment: If I understand correct - interceptor add header to each Request to server? How it can help me if my server doesn't know about this header?

Comment: this cache headers won't be sent to server.Okhttp will react as it came from server and it will obey the max-age rule. in short it will use local data instead of asking to server. Nice solution.